# Como faz pra somar todos valores do vetor em Python?

Tags: python

Como posso fazer para somar todos os valores? Devo utilizar um vetor (lista) para armazenar os valores.

```
valores = []

for i in range(1,11):
    valores.append(input('Informe o {}º valor: '.format(i)))
```

Comment: Plinio, se um dia você for editar a pergunta, adicione as informações relevantes no corpo, e não no título. :)

Comment: Obrigado pela dica!, me desculpe, é que eu sou novo aqui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma vez que você tenha uma lista numérica, pode utilizar a função embutida [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#sum) para somar os elementos. Por exemplo:

```
total = sum([1, 2, 3])
print(total) # 6
```

No entanto, note que, no seu código, você está criando uma lista em que cada membro tem o tipo `str` (retornado pela função `input`). Portanto, antes de adicionar os membros à lista, você há de convertê-los ao tipo adequado:

```
valores = []

for i in range(1, 11):
    valores.append(int(input('Informe o {}º valor: '.format(i))))

print(sum(valores))
```

Note que agora, antes de adicionar à lista, usamos [`int`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#int) para converter o valor fornecido ao tipo correto (nesse caso, será convertido para um tipo de número inteiro). Poderia utilizar [`float`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#float) se valores com ponto flutuante fossem passíveis de entrada.

Não se esqueça que `int` e `float` podem lançar um [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) se o argumento passado for inválido.

Algumas pessoas podem preferir utilizar uma [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) para esse tipo de coisa:

```
valores = [int(input(f"Informe o {i}º valor: ")) for i in range(1, 11)]
print(sum(valores))
```

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, me ajudou bastante aqui!

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import reduce

valores = []

for i in range(1, 11):
    valores.append(int(input(f'Informe o {i}º valor: ')))
```

Uma forma alternativa é utilizar a função `reduce`. Ela agrega os valores numa única saída.

```
reduce(lambda x, y : x + y, valores)
```